# Largest ring size ever used in a Monero transacation

Tags: transaction-size, ringsize, transaction-hash

What is the largest ring size ever used in a Monero transaction?

What was the size of that transaction in kB?

Please share the transaction ID if available

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Monero Blocks statistics the highest pre RingCT ringsize was [850](http://moneroblocks.info/stats/ring-size). I was not able to immediately locate that transaction on the blockchain.

I was able to find a sample [150](http://moneroblocks.info/search/42b01d86f88665037920f22fade4cac7f108d45dd067e54f77c5c3a052396aa8) mixin transaction from block 1,067,631 with a size of 70,219 bytes and a transaction fee of 0.69 XMR.

The above pre RingCT ring size and transaction size records were prior to the introduction of RingCT. With the recent [v0.10.3.1 point release](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/62e1mc/mandatory_upgrade_monero_01031_wolfram/) a new dynamic block size limiter algorithm was introduced to account for the unexpectedly fast adoption of RingCT.

Someone recently completed a transaction with a [new record ringsize of 4500](http://moneroblocks.info/search/5e75b4596c234ad17d34c44c3f07da508afb985748b3066bbfe2923cedb0b81a) with a size of 306,775 bytes and tx fee of 0.093729000000 XMR. This transaction appears to be near current limits, with anything larger [according to smooth](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/67c2os/lol_tx_with_5000_mixin_wonder_if_this_is_the/dgpd73w/) likely being:

> too big relative to fee and penalty (unless the block size grows).
>   If it were slightly smaller, say 4000 instead of 5000, it likely would confirm and with a fee of less than $2. That's a pretty nice demo of how to achieve an extreme degree of untracability at significant but not obscene cost.